# FBSession: No AppID provided; either pass an AppID to init, or add a string valued key

Tags: ios, facebook

When I open a FBSession (FB SDK 3.0), I get this error:

```
FBSession: No AppID provided; either pass an AppID to init, or add a string
valued key with the appropriate id named FacebookAppID to the bundle *.plist
```

I know I can add a value for FacebookAppID in the .plist, but what method should I use to init the FBSession with an AppId? I have tried using [FBSession setDefaultAppID] but that doesn't seem to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally you have to call initWithAppId: from the Facebook SDK.

```
- (id)initWithAppId:(NSString *)app_id
    andDelegate:(id<FBSessionDelegate>)delegate;
```

See here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/iossdk/authentication/

Comment: Thanks - I was trying to call it statically, derp

Answer (score 11):

This seems to work for me:

```
[FBSettings setDefaultAppID: @"123456789"];
```

Answer (score 9):

The new version of SDK doesn't accept

```
- (id)initWithAppId:(NSString *)app_id
    andDelegate:(id<FBSessionDelegate>)delegate;
```

so Create a FacebookAppID in the info.plist file and give the app id as string input.

Answer (score 2):

For me this issue appeared because my project for some odd reason (probably trigger happy with my copy and pasting from previous projects) had 2 plist files! So this information was not present on the plist being read for the FacebookAppID. I deleted the plist I didn't want then went back to my app's General settings and selected the plist I wanted in the 'Identity' section. Boom! Fixed